# Errors compiling SDL2 code

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++, sdl-2

I'm trying to follow a SDL2 tutorial at Lazy Foo: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php

I have done the tutorial and my window appears when the program is executed, even though I get a lot of compile errors when compiling the tutorial code. When I use the g++ compiler the errors are:

```
g++ sdl -w -lSDL2

sdl:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
sdl: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
sdl: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
sdl: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
sdl: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
sdl: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `\__TMC_END__'
sdl:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in sdl(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:11: all] Error 1
```

I don't know what these compile errors mean or how to solve them. I tried using the gcc compiler but the same errors appear. Can someone help me learn how to properly compile SDL2 code? What is my mistake? My Makefile is as follows:

```
# CC specifies which compiler we're using
CC = g++

# C_FLAGS specifies addicional compiler flags
CFLAGS = -w -lSDL2

#TARGETS specifies source files to be compiled
TARGETS = sdl

all: $(TARGETS)
    $(CC) $(TARGETS) $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETS)
```

Comment: `#TARGETS specifies source files to be compiled` it actually doesn't, but specify the targets.

Comment: Do you have your own headers? Did you forget a header guard?

Comment: What is an `sdl` file that you're trying to link with libsdl? Where did it came from? Is a source code saved in that file? If so - it just asks for problems, and `-w` reassures compiler that you're actually want that problems.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite know what the error means, but it seems like you are linking wrong files while compiling.

Since you asked I can tell you how I compile C programs in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
(I only use text editor and terminal)

Here is the command:

```
$gcc main.c -o outputfile -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer \`sld2-config --cflags --libs`

-lSDL2_image: library for image handling
-lSDL2_mixer: library for audio handling
```